# Dates subtraction from different rows of data frame

Tags: r

I have big data frame (dim: 12867779x5) which looks like that:

| id | group | date1 | date 2 | icf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 2 | 2020-03-17 | 2019-06-05 |  |
| id1 | 3 | 2020-04-03 | 2019-05-09 |  |
| id2 | 2 | 2020-04-10 | 2019-07-04 |  |
| id2 | 3 | 2021-04-1 | 2020-06-01 |  |
| id3 | 1 | 2020-04-13 | 2019-07-07 |  |
| id3 | 2 | 2021-04-10 | 2020-06-01 |  |
| id3 | 3 | 2020-04-10 | 2019-07-04 |  |
| id3 | 4 | 2021-04-13 | 2020-06-01 |  |

Desired output:

| id | group | date1 | date 2 | icf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 3 | 2020-04-03 | 2019-05-09 | 0 |
| id2 | 2 | 2020-04-10 | 2019-07-04 | 52 |
| id2 | 3 | 2021-04-01 | 2020-06-01 | 0 |
| id3 | 1 | 2020-04-13 | 2019-07-07 | 49 |
| id3 | 2 | 2021-04-10 | 2020-06-01 | -646 |
| id3 | 3 | 2020-04-10 | 2019-07-04 | 52 |
| id3 | 4 | 2021-04-13 | 2020-06-01 | 0 |

To calculate icf I need to check if the id's from row i and i+1 are the same. If yes icf = date2(i+1) - date1(i).

I wrote this function to calculate icf, but it's too slow. I'm looking for ways to speed it up, I was thinking about using the apply function but I don't have idea how to re-write this icfCalculation fucntion.

```
icfCalculation <- function(dataFrame){
  nr <- nrow(dataFrame) - 1
  for (i in 1:nr) {
    if(dataFrame[i, 1] == dataFrame[i+1, 1]){
      dataFrame[i,5] = dataFrame[i+1, 4] - dataFrame[i, 3]
    } 
    else{
      dataFrame[i,5] = 0
    }
  }
  return(dataFrame)
}
```

Comment: Would you attach your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for putting expected output. This is not the same as what you have put - but it does give the same results as your function and should be significantly quicker to thanks to the `data.table` internal optimisations:

```r
library(data.table)

# Read in data 
dat  <- read.table(text = "id   group   date1   date2   
id1 2   2020-03-17  2019-06-05  
id1 3   2020-04-03  2019-05-09  
id2 2   2020-04-10  2019-07-04  
id2 3   2021-04-1   2020-06-01  
id3 1   2020-04-13  2019-07-07  
id3 2   2021-04-10  2020-06-01  
id3 3   2020-04-10  2019-07-04  
id3 4   2021-04-13  2020-06-01", 
    h = T, 
    colClasses = c("character", "character", "Date", "Date")
)

# Make it a data.table
setDT(dat)

dat[, icf := fifelse(
    id == shift(id, type = "lead"), 
    as.integer(
        shift(date2, type = "lead") - date1
        ), 
    0)
]
dat
#     id group      date1      date2  icf
# 1: id1     2 2020-03-17 2019-06-05 -313
# 2: id1     3 2020-04-03 2019-05-09    0
# 3: id2     2 2020-04-10 2019-07-04   52
# 4: id2     3 2021-04-01 2020-06-01    0
# 5: id3     1 2020-04-13 2019-07-07   49
# 6: id3     2 2021-04-10 2020-06-01 -646
# 7: id3     3 2020-04-10 2019-07-04   52
# 8: id3     4 2021-04-13 2020-06-01   NA
```

If you want the last NA to be 0, just add `dat$icf[nrow(dat)]  <- 0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(icf = replace_na(ifelse(id == lead(id), lead(date2) - date1, 0), 0))
```

Rather than use `tidyr::replace_na` you could also specify the `default` argument of `lead`.

**Base R**

A base R approach would be something like:

```
df$icf <- with(df, ifelse(id == c(id[2:nrow(df)], NA), c(date2[2:nrow(df)], NA) - date1, 0))
```

**Output**

```
   id group      date1      date2  icf
1 id1     2 2020-03-17 2019-06-05 -313
2 id1     3 2020-04-03 2019-05-09    0
3 id2     2 2020-04-10 2019-07-04   52
4 id2     3 2021-04-01 2020-06-01    0
5 id3     1 2020-04-13 2019-07-07   49
6 id3     2 2021-04-10 2020-06-01 -646
7 id3     3 2020-04-10 2019-07-04   52
8 id3     4 2021-04-13 2020-06-01    0
```